# How to work out percentage change with inverse proportionality?

Tags: inverse, percentages

$$a \propto  \frac{1}{b}$$

If $a$ increases by 10%, how would one work out the percentage change of $b$, without knowing the value  of either variable?

Comment: If $a,b$ change to $a',b'$ then by inverse proportionality $\displaystyle \frac{a'}{a}=\frac{1}{b'} \Big/ \frac{1}{b}=\frac{b}{b'}\,$. Now if $\displaystyle\frac{a'}{a}=110\%=1.1\,$, then $\displaystyle \frac{b'}{b}=\cdots\;$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inverse proportion means: $a\cdot b=k$.

Hence:
$$1.1a\cdot \frac{1}{1.1}b=k \Rightarrow \frac{1}{1.1}-1=-\frac{1}{11}.$$

Comment: You are welcome.